# How to test a pallet that depends on the staking pallet?

Tags: pallet, testing, pallet-staking

If I have a pallet that depends on the staking pallet, and for example one of the functions needs access to the active era, how can I set up the test environment so that I can actually test this?

Let's say I am accessing the active era like this:

```rust
let active_era = Staking::<T>::active_era().ok_or(/*...*/)
```

I have checked the `mock.rs` file in the `staking` pallet directory, and it sets up all the configs and sets up the environment needed for testing the `staking` pallet.

For my pallet, I need to set up the staking pallet because my pallet is dependent on it.
I was thinking of accessing the `ExtBuilder` from the staking pallet, but it is a bit more complex than just importing it at the beginning of the file. It's because the `staking/src/mock.rs` file is only compiled when testing the pallet. So when I am testing only my pallet it isn't possible to access the `ExtBuilder` from the staking pallet.
This means that I can't access anything from the `mock.rs` file inside the staking pallet.

How should I go about setting up the `staking` pallet for testing my own pallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the Staking Pallet into your mock `construct_runtime!`:

From `frame/session/benchmarking/src/mock.rs`:

```rust
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},
        Staking: pallet_staking::{Pallet, Call, Config<T>, Storage, Event<T>},
        Session: pallet_session::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event, Config<T>},
    }
);
```

At this point, you should be able to access public functions from the staking module via the `Staking` struct which is defined in the `construct_runtime!`.

So you should be able to call:

```rust
let active_era = Staking::<T>::active_era().ok_or(/*...*/)
```

Exactly as you have wanted in your main post.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of that, I am interested in setting up the environment for testing. Currently, if I call the `active_era` function like this I will get `None` as the result. I need to have some active era and also, define some stakers and potentially nominators like it is done in the `staking` pallet. I should have been more specific in my question.

Comment: It seems you will need to also add the Session pallet. Take a look at the tests here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/tests.rs#L761

Comment: I think I have found a solution actually, I just need to configure the `GenesisConfig` of the staking pallet if I am not mistaken(for configuring stakers). Edit: For the active era I will look into the tests you have sent me :)